# ¿Cómo añadir caché solo a una parte de la web? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy intentando añadir Django caché a mi proyecto pero tengo bastantes dudas sobre ese tema.

Quiero añadir caché a la búsqueda de productos de la página home y búsqueda.

Ésta es mi configuración ahora mismo:

### Settings

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/cache/memcached.sock',
    }
}
```

### Home

```
@method_decorator(cache_page(60*15), name='dispatch')
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'frontend/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if (self.request.user.is_authenticated):
            if Perfil.objects.filter(usuario = self.request.user).exists():
                perfil = Perfil.objects.get(usuario = self.request.user)
                context['perfil'] = perfil
                context['likes'] = Like.objects.filter(perfil=perfil)
                context['count_productos'] = contador_productos(perfil)
        return context
```

De está forma aunque esté logueado no me devuelve el objeto `perfil` ya que para loguearme primero debo entrar en ésta función una primera vez para mandar el formulario de login.

Comment: Hola, sería bueno que agregues tus modelos también

Comment: No creo que haga falta los modelos ya que solo quiero añadir caché a unas views, no influyen los modelos en eso.